# Cassandra - get multiple rows with column slice

Tags: cassandra

Is is possible to execute such query?

```
MultigetSliceQuery<String, String, String> multigetSliceQuery =
    HFactory.createMultigetSliceQuery(keyspace, stringSerializer, stringSerializer, stringSerializer);
multigetSliceQuery.setColumnFamily("Standard1");
multigetSliceQuery.setKeys("fake_key_0", "fake_key_1");
multigetSliceQuery.setRange("A", "C", false, 3);
Result<Rows<String, String, String>> result = multigetSliceQuery.execute();
```

Get rows by Key: "fake_key_0", "fake_key_1" AND column slice between A and C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok - it works:

http://gettingstartedwithcassandra.blogspot.com/2011/06/query-multiple-rows-with-range-in.html